# Can we use a variable in SQL?

Tags: sql

Im confused if it is possible to create a variable in sql and assign it values. 
This is my code from what i have already tried.

```
    select facultyName, count(programcode) as 'Highest Value'
    from program, faculty
    where program.FacultyCode = faculty.FacultyCode 
    group by facultyname
    having count(programcode) > 5;
```

This is my lecturers code

```
   SELECT t.FacultyName, t.ProgramCount 
   FROM (
            SELECT Faculty.FacultyName, COUNT(*) AS 'Program Count'
            FROM Program, Faculty
            WHERE Program.FacultyCode=Faculty.FacultyCode
            GROUP BY Faculty.FacultyCode) t GROUP BY t.FacultyName
            HAVING MAX (t.ProgramCount) = (SELECT (MAX(p.ProgramCount
                                   FROM (
                                         SELECT Faculty.FacultyName, COUNT(*) AS 'Program Count'
                                         FROM Faculty, Program
                                         WHERE Faculty.FacultyCode = Program.FacultyCode
                                         GROUP BY Faculty.FacultyName) )))p;
```

The output should be 5.

Comment: If your lecturer is using commas in the `FROM` clause, you should look for another class.

Comment: Im still confused how he ended up using for example, (p.FacultyCode) is this a possible syntax?

Comment: You have a strange lecturer - he/she is teaching you invalid standard SQL `as 'Highest Value'` is not valid according to the SQL standard. Is that a class for a specific database product?

Comment: Its not for a specific product. Its an assignment. I dont get it because he is using object referencing at the end of the query. i.e  ....)p;

Comment: Well, in (standard) SQL, identifiers are either not quoted at all, or if they contain characters that are not allowed for identifiers they have to be quoted with double quotes. `"Highest Value"` is an identifier, but `'Highest Value'` is a string constant and you can't use a string constant as an alias (identifier).